# Stop While loop in jmeter when condition is true

Tags: jmeter

My test plan structure is

```
Thread Group  
  --Http request    
while loop controller
  --http request
   --regular expression extractor (get a login config key which is used in while loop)
```

Regular expression:-`"business_type":"(.+?)"`
variable name :-`business_type`
while loop condition: :- `${__javaScript(("${business_type}" === "Apparel & Footwear" && ${counter} < 5),)`

I want to stop while loop when the expected business type is found in response.

Comment: you want to stop if it's `Apparel & Footwear` or if it's not empty/default value?

Comment: I want to stop when Apparel & Footwear is displayed in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check 2 condition while one for negative equal the string in [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller):

```
${__jexl3(${counter} < 5 && "${business_type}" != "Apparel & Footwear")}
```

Prefer __jexl3 over __javascript function:

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

Comment: so, I need to add If controller within while loop? @user7294900

Comment: No. Same statement can be used in while controller. No need for another if controller

Comment: can you please tell me the structure of Test Plan @user7294900

Comment: Same as you display in question

Comment: test execution is stopped after execution on HTTP request --1

Comment: If you don't need the counter you can use `${__jexl3("${business_type}" != "Apparel & Footwear")}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168235/discussion-between-kuldeep-yadav-and-user7294900).

Answer (score 0):

Try using "!=" instead of "===".
${__javaScript("${business_type}" != "Apparel & Footwear" && ${counter} < 5)}

Comment: While loop keeps going on after getting of Apparel & Footwear @sunny_teo

Comment: @Kuldeep From where you are getting the counter value? Your plan should contain a counter config below while loop controller.